# x86 assembly: Using #define'd constants as arguments in calls to to #define's macros

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, macros, x86

I'm working on manually constructing an IDT table in x86 assembly. I have the following macros defined using the C preprocessor in my .S file:

```
// sets up an entry in the idt for a trap type
#define SETUP_IDT_ENTRY( name, num, istrap, segment, dpl ) \
    lea name, %edx; \
    movl $(KCODE << 16), %eax; \
    movw $0x8e00, %dx; \
    lea (idt + (8 * num)), %edi; \
    movl %eax, (%edi); \
    movl %edx, 4(%edi);

// sample set of args to a call to setup_dt_entry
#define M_DIVIDE _t_divide_ep, T_DIVIDE, 0, KCODE, 0

// the call
SETUP_IDT_ENTRY( M_DIVIDE )
```

However, gcc complains: `error: macro "SETUP_IDT_ENTRY" requires 5 arguments, but only 1 given`

I thought that #define'd arguments to #define'd functions were expanded before the function call was evaluated, in which case `M_DIVIDE` would expand to the five arguments required and `SETUP_IDT_ENTRY` would be happy. I've tried various combinations of parentheses and nothing seems to be working; is there a way to make this work?

Note: I know there are alternate approaches for building IDT's in x86 assembly, but that's not the question I'm trying to answer here; I'm just trying to figure out if macros can be expanded as macro arguments.

Comment: Full disclosure: the work in question (IDT table) is related to a course assignment, but I feel that the specific question regarding macro expansion is unrelated enough that there's no conflict of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments themselves are expanded, but the number of arguments must match the macro definition. You'll need an extra macro to make it work:

```
#define IDT1(x) SETUP_IDT_ENTRY(x)

IDT1(M_DIVIDE)
```

More info [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html) and [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan).

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with another layer of indirection:

```
#define PLEASE_SETUP_IDT_ENTRY(...) SETUP_IDT_ENTRY(__VA_ARGS__)
// the delicate, civilized call
PLEASE_SETUP_IDT_ENTRY(M_DIVIDE)
```

(Variadic macro is not necessary if we want a new variant to accept one and only one argument. The above definition accepts one *or* multiple arguments).